# Continuous AJAX call Blocks page, Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firefox

this is first time I'm facing the issue. I have used AJAX many times.

I'm calling an AJAX to update page content. AJAX call is after each 2 sec. For some Hits it working properly but after that I'm getting following Alert on **FIREFOX browser**

[image]

And this happens only on **FIREFOX**, I'm not getting such a alert on **chore browser**

My Code is :

```
function search_by_location (location_id) {  
    console.log(location_id);

    setInterval(function(){ 

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "<?php echo BASE_URL.'controller/function'?>",
            data:{"key":location_id},
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                $("#custom_div").html("");
                $("#custom_div").html(data);
                search_by_location (location_id);
            },
            error:function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

What is the issue ? I think this is because multiple hits and page update. Is it cache related thing ?

Comment: I think the issue because of setinterval. because of the i think on every 2000 of time period the same code is executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're making the AJAX request every 2 seconds, but you're *also* starting a new timer every time a request completes. Therefore the number of requests you're making grows exponentially. You should remove the `search_by_location()` call in the `success` handler:

```
function search_by_location (location_id) {  
    setInterval(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo BASE_URL.'controller/function'?>",
            data: { key: location_id },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#custom_div").html(data);
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

Also note that a better pattern to follow is to use `setTimeout()` on the successful completion of a request. This will stop requests from backing up on the client when they take longer to complete than the poll interval:

```
function search_by_location (location_id) {  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo BASE_URL.'controller/function'?>",
        data: { key: location_id },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#custom_div").html(data);
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                search_by_location(location_id);
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

You may also want to look in to using websockets if you require the client to always have immediate access to up-to-date data. Polling patterns can end up DDoS-ing your own server if you aren't careful.